# How to add special characters while scripting InDesign with Python

Tags: python, adobe-indesign

How to add InDesign special characters like auto-page-numbers to textframes when using Python for scripting InDesign? With JS you could do:

```
aTextFrame.contents = SpecialCharacters.autoPageNumber
```

Comment: In the InDesign search dialog box you can find the page number markers with `^N`. So perhaps `aTextFrame.contents = "^N"` or somehting similar *may* work. Disclaimer: I don't know Python.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad `'^M'` would be what I want to use, but it appears as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant for special character auto page number marker is

```
idAutoPageNumber = 1396797550 # from enum idSpecialCharacters
```

See [doc_reference](https://github.com/lohriialo/indesign-scripting-python/tree/master/api_reference) for complete Python Scripting object definitions for InDesign

To add the special character to a textframe:

```
aTextFrame.contents = idAutoPageNumber
```